# Mongo non directional graph database

Tags: mongodb, graph, mongodb-query, graph-databases

I need to create a graph database based on MongoDB and its $graphlookup func to answer the following problem:

Lets assume I have a list of transaction between people. here is an example of a transaction:

```
{
  from: "A",
  to: "B",
  value: 1
}
```

I need to create a non directional graph that describes this connections. every node should be a person and every edge should have a volume: the number of transactions these 2 people made between them.

for example if i am given the following list:

```
[
{
  from: "A",
  to: "B",
  value: 1
},
{
  from: "B",
  to: "A",
  value: 3
}
]
```

Both of these transaction should represented by one edge with a volume of 2.

My problem is I don't see how mongo $graphlookup can create a non-directional relationships.

Should the data be preprocessed before uploading it to the mongodb database?
How should I query it to achieve a non-directional graph like results?

I need to achive the following results.
given the input:

```
[
  {
    from: "A",
    to: "B",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    from: "B",
    to: "A",
    value: 3
  },
  {
    from: "C",
    to: "A",
    value: 6
  },
  {
    from: "C",
    to: "A",
    value: 10
  },
  {
    from: "A",
    to: "C",
    value: 20
  }
]
```

I want to create a graphlookup that will return something of this sort:

```
{
   "startedAddress": "A",
   "neighboors": [
      {"address": "C", "volume": 3, "depth": 1},
      {"address": "B", "volume": 2, "depth": 1}
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of depth > 1?

Answer (score 1):

Use `$setUnion` to create an array to store the 2 ends of the edges and use the result as id to perform `$group` to sum the volume.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "$setUnion": [
          [
            "$from"
          ],
          [
            "$to"
          ]
        ]
      },
      "volume": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HKBK_e9cZAv)

Comment: How would you traverse this graph using graph lookup?

Comment: just did. lmk if that sufficient